# Angry Birds and other games force close (crash) on startup when using Simple2Ext (S2E)

Tags: htc-desire, cyanogenmod, app2sd

I'm running CM 7.03 on my HTC Desire (GSM) and have successfully partitioned my SD card with a 512mb ext4 partition. I installed S2E and it moved my apps to /sd-ext successfully, but certain apps now crash at startup. Angry Birds, Cut The Rope etc will force close as soon as they're launched. Other apps work just fine. I'm assuming it's apps with native code that have issues, as pure Java ones seem ok.

Has anyone else experienced this problem, and if so, how did you fix it? If I can't find a work around, I will have to delete my partition and just put up with small storage space.

Comment: I would try backing up the data for one of the apps, then clearing it and seeing if it works afterwards.

Comment: You sir are a genius. If you'd like to post this comment as an answer, I will gladly award you 15 internet points.
The only downside is that I've now lost all my save games for Angry Birds, Cut The Rope etc. At least they're working though :)

Comment: Hahaha.  Done, gimme my internet points :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try backing up the data for one of the apps, then clearing it and seeing if it works afterwards.

You could try just restoring `/data/data/com.rovio.angrybirds/files/highscores.lua` and see if that works.  I don't have Cut the Rope so I don't know how its files work, sorry!